# PM2 and Node: why am I getting env variable undefined?

Tags: node.js, npm, pm2

Platform: Windows

What I want to do is simple: start pm2 (without any .json scripts) and have my node web app (ExpressJS) access the env. variable.

when I do set

```
> set MODE=test
```

and then do

```
> npm start
```

I can access process.env.MODE which gives me 'test' exactly as I wanted.

Now I can't seem to figure out how to do this in pm2. If I

```
> set MODE=test
```

and then do

```
pm2 start ./bin/www
```

I get process.env.MODE is undefined

I also tried

```
pm2 start ./bin/www -x -- --MODE=test
```

also tried

```
set MODE="test" & pm2 start ./bin/www
```

and

```
set MODE=test & pm2 start ./bin/www
```

Nothing seems to work. What am I doing wrong? What should I do instead?

Comment: i guess that is because `pm2` will spawn a new shell. Try `pm2 start env MODE=test ./bin/www` that should work i guess

Answer (score 0):

On Windows SET sets an environment variable in the current CMD session. You may need to SET your environment variable in the same CMD session that you are running pm2 from.

Alternately, use SETX to set a permanent environment variable. You need to close and re-open and CMD sessions in order to make an environment variable set with SETX available in all CMD sessions.

refer: https://superuser.com/questions/916649/what-is-the-difference-between-setx-and-set-in-environment-variables-in-windows